# Visual Studio: DLL locations for release

Tags: visual-studio, dll, release

I have a project that I am working on that references a "Common Library (DLL)". In the DevEnv it works fine, however if I build and try to organize my files it doesn't work. Basically if I have things setup like so:

- C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe
- C:\Program Files\MyApp\Common\WPF Commons.dll
- C:\Program Files\MyApp\Modules\SomeModule.dll
- etc

MyApp.exe doesn't work. It tries to look only in the current directory for the DLL files. So how do I set it up in Visual Studio so that when I build the application knows to look for the DLLs in those other folders?

Oh, and I realize that it does work in Dev because all the DLLs are put in the same folder. I don't want to do that for release though :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is add a private probing path into the application configuration file. This tells the CLR which directories to look in for extra assemblies.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx

Sample app.config

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="Common;Modules"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is there an alternate solution aside from copying the MyApp.exe.config file (which can be opened and edited after the fact easily)?

Comment: @myermian you could override the assembly resolve event to do custom resolution.  However personally I would go with the app.config one.  app.config is *meant* to be editted after the fact to allow for administrators to clean up binding and deployment issues.  It's standard practice to use it for probing paths (Visual Studio in fact does this).